# Is there a solution to change table names in Cognos framework model automatically?

Tags: sdk, cognos

Currently, there are a lot of old tables existing in framework model A in Cognos content store, we need rename these old tables to new tables(old tables structure are same to new tables, but their name are different) automatically, not manually, not by framework manager. Anyone has idea about it? could you share me? many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would help very much if you clarify what the situation is. Your terminology is confusing.

The Cognos content store is the data base which stores everything which appears in the UI of Cognos Analytics.  This includes the data source connection definitions, reports, and administration functionality like the memberships of groups and roles.

It is controlled by Cognos and you would very much like not touch it and alter it.

The objects in a Framework manager model are not stored in the content store.  When you publish a package, the information in the package is written into the content store. Where is not something you should need to know.

My understanding about your question is this:

Some tables in a data base which is used in your FM model have had their name changed.  You want to alter the model so that the model uses the new tables rather than the old ones.

There is extensive functionality in the FM UI to deal with cases such as the remapping to new source functionality.

It should be possible to programmatically alter the model.

The nature of the change of the tables is important.

1. If the nature of the renaming has been that you have changed the case of the tables from any of all upper case or all lower case or a mix of case table names and you have made them all lower case or all upper case and if you have 11.1.7 then you can use this utility.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_fm.doc/c_fm_model_update_util.html

The utility does not have provision to specify a subset of tables to have their case changed.  It will do the action on all of the data source query subjects. This might be a problem in your case.

2.
I have never needed to do this and, subsequently, do not know if this would really work but you could edit the action logs.  This would entail looking through the metadata import actions and the modelling actions which refer to the tables which were renamed and editing them to refer to the new tables.

You would really need to understand the action logs.

For example, if you happen to have expanded the node in the UI for any of the tables, views, or synonyms when you did the metadata import, the action log will have decided to do an import of the list of the the tables ( or views etc.) of the data base. This happens even if you closed the node.  If you didn't then the metadata import as captured in the action log will import every table (or view etc.) generically.  This means that if a table has been added, the action log playback will import it and if a table has been deleted, then the action log playback will not fail because it could not find the table. Why such a state could ever happen is beyond me but that is what happens.

Do this on a copy.  That should not be necessary to mention but you never know.

You would need to be absolutely sure that no-one decided that they were clever and manually edited the model.xml file.  Manual editing does not get captured in the action logs.

You would need to be absolutely sure that no-one decided that they were clever and deleted some or all of the log files in the Cognos project.

You would need to be **really really really** sure that this is better than remapping.  Frankly, the time invested in importing the new tables and remapping your model to use them would probably be less than the time invested in editing and then running the action logs, and then wading through the model to make sure you have not mucked things up.

Also, I don't know if editing the action logs is allowed in the licence so you could end up getting IBM mad at you.

Comment: Hi C'est Moi,

Sorry for confusing you. I am new to Cognos. It should be "change the table name in query subject defined in model.xml of the package". Now we are going to develop a Java program using Cognos SDK/Axis to 
1. export the the model xml from package 
2. modify the model xml to replace the old table with new one
3. import the modified model xml to the package

but we are no idea which Cognos SDK/Axis API/function could be used?...

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your vocabulary that you are very new to Cognos...

The appropriate solution depends on how you define "a lot".  Your Framework Manager model can be edited manually or by a program you write in C# or Java that leverages the Cognos Framework Manager SDK.  Cognos SDKs are not trivial.  There is a steep learning curve.  In my experience, if "a lot" means less than a few hundred, you should do this manually.  An experienced Framework Manager modeler could probably get through a hundred tables in an afternoon.

Comment: Hi Dougp,

Yes, "a lot" means around thousands. Also, these tables would be changed regularly.